# is it possible to send the remote connector ip via netcat?

Tags: ip, netcat

Actually I want to make something like [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me) functionality but only for my internal network. I see it the way something on server listens some port and send ip of connected remote machine.

Seems `nc` is a great utility for my issue (also I haven't any php/python/whatever on server. just only shell and standard unix tools).

I can see remote ip and dns name if I launch `nc -vv` and connect to it from remote system, but I can't find the way to send them to remote host.

Or maybe I chose too strange path and there is another simpler solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
while true; do nc -lvp 1337 -c "echo -n 'Your IP is: '; grep connect my.ip | cut -d'[' -f 3 | cut -d']' -f 1" 2> my.ip; done
```

`nc` will be executed in endless loop listening on port `1337` with verbose option that will write information about remote host to `stderr`. `stderr` is redirected to file `my.ip`. Option `-c` for `nc` allows to execute something to "handle" connection. In this case we will next grep for IP addres from `my.ip` file.

```
pbm@lantea:~$ curl http://tauri:1337
Your IP is: 192.168.0.100
```

Comment: Just wow! Never thought that it is possible to redirect output to file and read it in command execution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do nc -l -v 3333 2> status | while read msg; do ip=$(cat status | grep -o -P '(?<=from).*(?=port)') && notify-send "$ip" "$msg" -i gtk-network; done ; done
```

Redirect **stderr** to a file called **status**; then it reads ip of remote connector from the file; finally shows the ip in notify-osd message.

[image: nc remote-connector screenshots]

---

**Note:**
when someone connects to the same port from another computer **nc** gerneally puts this to stderr: `connection from 10.10.0.1 port 3333 [tcp/*] accepted`. I simply
extract the ip address using **grep**.